# Mockito-ing to always throw exceptions except on specific methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

How can I create a mock with Mockito that throws an exception on every method call except on some stubbed calls? Intuitively, I tried it by providing a default answer like this:

```
Iterator themock = mock(Iterator.class, 
    new ThrowsExceptionClass(UnsupportedOperationException.class));
when(themock.hasNext()).thenReturn(false);
assertFalse(themock.hasNext());
```

but the call `themock.hasNext()` in the second line already throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mockito cannot know that the call themock.hasNext() in the second line is during stubbing since the actual call to when is done after that call has completed. If you use the [doReturn](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.21/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12) for mocking, it does know that and doesn't apply the default answer:

```
Iterator themock = mock(Iterator.class, 
    new ThrowsExceptionClass(UnsupportedOperationException.class));
doReturn(false).when(themock).hasNext();
assertFalse(themock.hasNext());
```